# Force to download .ics file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, calendar

I think my question is very particular. What I'm doing right now is creating a simple list of events where you can click each of them an add to your calendar (iCal, Google Calendar, Live Calendar, etc.). To achieve this i'm using [addToCalentar](https://github.com/tardate/jquery.addtocalendar) but there is something acting weird in this code.

When I select iCal it's suppose to download an ics file but the plugin open a new browser tab showing the file itself. All the other options are working very good, because their needs to open in a new window. But muy question is. Where can I modify the source code in order to only download the file if the user selects "iCal" option?

**This is my HTML:**

```
<div class="addtocal">
    <div>01/04/2015 <span title="invite.ics"></span> </div>
</div>
```

**This is my Plugin Configuration:**

```
$('.addtocal').AddToCal({
      icalEnabled:true,
      vcalEnabled:false,

      getEventDetails: function( element ) {
        var
          dtstart_element = element.find('.dtstart'), start,
          dtend_element = element.find('.dtend'), end,
          title_element = element.find('.summary'), title,
          details_element = element.find('.description'), details,
          ics_element = element.find('.ics'), ics;



        start = dtstart_element.length ? dtstart_element.attr('title') : new Date();

        if(dtend_element.length) {
          end = dtend_element.attr('title');

        } else {

          end = new Date();
          end.setTime(end.getTime() + 60 * 60 * 1000);

        }

        title = title_element.length ? title_element.html() : element.attr('id');
        details = details_element.length ? details_element.html() : element.html();

        ics = ics_element.attr('title');

        // return the required event structure
        return {
          webcalurl: null,
          icalurl: ics,
          vcalurl: null,
          start: start,
          end: end,
          title: title,
          details: details,
          location: null,
          url: null
          };
      },
    });
```

**This is the referenced plugin:**

https://github.com/tardate/jquery.addtocalendar/blob/master/jquery.addtocal.js

What I was working on is changing this method to determine if the `item.label` is iCal I can add `<a download>...</>` but is not working.

```
_renderItem: function( ul, item) {

      return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.addtocal", item )
        .append( $( "<a></a>" ).text( item.label ) )
        .appendTo( ul );
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

To force your browser to download a file instead of reading it, you can give it a `FileType` header that will force it to download.

If you do not have a .htaccess file yet, make one in your webroot folder, and add this:

`AddType application/octet-stream .ics`

That will force browsers to download *.ics files instead of showing them.